# Controlling five Android phones with PC

Tags: android

I'm looking to use five android phones to take a photo simultaneously (from different angles).

I'd like to control the phones via a pc (linux or mac) and ideally they're all connected via USB/Ethernet.

I'm an EE, but I don't have much Android experience, so looking to get some feedback based on what I've read so far.

1. Looks like the Scrcpy library could work here, controlling the 5 devices via adb. I see it allows for multiple connections, have anyone tried this?
2. I could potentially create a PCB that integrates with the headphone jack of each device and control via push button and 470ohm resistor?
3. I could potentially build a client app on the Android devices, which connects to a server app on linux/mac (basic TCP/IP client server)

What routes/design would people take on architect-ing such a system?

Thanks for your help and reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "simultaneous"?  How much leeway do you have-  seconds?  Milliseconds? Somewhere in between? Because those can require different techniques.

The easiest thing is to use adb on all 5 devices (I think you can, but I've never personally done more than 2 at once).  YOu can even use adb over wifi, so you don't need the cables.  You can open the photo app on each (either manually or via adb) then send an input command down via db to each device to send a click of a CAMERA media button, which *should* cause them to take a photo (of course this is dependent on the camera app honoring this keycode).

The problem with that approach is that you're going to have to have a script that either sends commands to each device 1 at a time (they'll be off by seconds) or spawns N processes that each send a command.  That obviously isn't going to be simultaneous either, although it would be closer.

If you really do need simultaneous, its better to write an app on the PC that sends a UDP multicast message.  Write an Android app that listens for it.  Then when the device receives the message, take the picture.  This will assure each device gets the message at the same time, and the picture should be within milliseconds of each other.  Of course, if you don't need ms resolution this is total overkill.

Comment: Thank you for the genuine questions - it is a bit embarrassing I forgot to mention those aspects. 
I was hoping all of these images could be taken at the same time - milliseconds if not micro (I know we're not dealing with RTOS here).

I am quite familiar on how to deal with tcp/ip in rust/c++/python, now I guess it will be a battle of understanding the android ecosystem and building something that can handle being the client.


If you have any information on handling the android part - I would be all ears. Thanks again for the informative answer and questions.

Comment: You won't get microseconds (I think doing that with any non-specialized hardware would be hard) but I think milliseconds is achievable.  The socket is just plain Java sockets (DatagramSocket) inside an Activity that will need to be foreground.  If you can't do that, use a foreground Service.  Look into the Camera2 API to actually take the picture.  I do think the UDP multicast is the way to go-  it removes the PC script itself as a timing issue, and brings it down to wifi travel time (speed of light) and OS level delays in response.

Comment: I'd also point out-  if you need highly correlated times, try to use the same devices with minimal apps installed and freshly rebooted.  This will minimize delays due to other apps winning the scheduler, and it will minimize differences in time to take a photo due to the camera sensor itself.  I would make sure that if you try to correlate photos, you log the time you get the message and the time you take the photo on each, as they won't have the same timestamps-  no clocks are perfectly in sync.  But the delta between receiving the messages is a good proxy for the delta between the clocks.

Comment: You are amazing - thank you for those detailed responses. 

What do you think about handling time sync'ing on the android side - where I pass in a timestamp to capture photos at (from the PC) and the devices capture photos at that particular time, but forcing them to do a timesync immediately before?

Comment: If you're thinking a timesync like timed and trying to update system time, I don't think that's too great-  there's a lot of variability  just from the network requests to your source of truth. What you could do is just send a message with the current pc timestamp, check your own timestamp, and figure out the delta.  Then you could send all the take picture commands with a time in PC time, and just subtract the delta to figure out local time.

Comment: If you try to do this, I recommend creating a thread for taking pictures on, and have it sleep until that time comes up.  That will be more accurate than an AlarmManager alert.  The sleep can either be an actual sleep() call, or a HandlerThread with a delayed message posted to it.  The difference between those two mechanisms should be microseconds.  The second is better if you want to enqueue multiple take picture commands